# Use one AAD App Registration for Web-API and WPF Client APP

Tags: wpf, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt

I'm trying to use one AAD App-Registration for both, a Web-API and a WPF Client APP. I've managed to configure the App-Registration correctly for my Web-API, but now I want to add a Native-Client APP to the same Registration, where a WEB-Registration is allready set up.
It works for me if I'm using only one of them, so if i register only the Web App it works. The same is true for the Native-Client App.
So I'm wondering if it is possible to combine those two and only use one App-Registration.

This is the error I get when trying to acquire a token with both registrations:

```
MSAL.NetCore.4.25.0.0.MsalServiceException: 
            ErrorCode: invalid_client
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. 
You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  
Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use one AAD App Registration for both is not recommended although it seems to be able to meet your identity authentication needs. But generally we will need to use app roles or some other configurations, it will be very confusing in this case. It's recommended to use 2 app registrations. The `AADSTS7000218` error means you didn't put `client_secret`, which is a small error that you can resolve it easily. If you still need help on this issue, please show how you are acquiring the token. Using what auth flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one AAD App Registration for both is not recommended although it seems to be able to meet your identity authentication needs. But generally we will need to use app roles or some other configurations, it will be very confusing in this case. It's recommended to use 2 app registrations.

The `AADSTS7000218` error means you didn't put client_secret.

[image]